# Should I use Browserify or Webpack for lazy loading of dependencies in angular 1.x

Tags: angularjs, browserify, webpack

I would like to have async loading of angular dependencies in a large application and I'm trying to decide between [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) for this. I know angular 2.0 will support this natively but for now I'm looking for a well supported and popular solution.

Can anyone give advice on which ones works best in an angular team and the most optimal way to structure the project.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

At my company, we've switched over from browserify to webpack for a multitude of reasons, lazy loading being one of them.

Putting things in multiple bundles in browserify took some configuration changes as well as special code. Here is a great guide for that http://esa-matti.suuronen.org/blog/2013/04/15/asynchronous-module-loading-with-browserify/

With webpack, adding a new bundle just means an extra entry file line in the configuration's entry file line. Here is a quick guide to that: https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto#7-multiple-entrypoints. In the case of lazy-loading, you don't even need to change anything in the configuration file, which is awesome - just use the asynchronous `require` syntax detailed here: https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto#9-async-loading

Here is a template for a setup very similar to what we use at https://bench.co in production. https://github.com/jeffling/angular-webpack-example/

Comment: [Extend version of the Angular Phonecat tutorial with added steps to include webpack and gulp](https://github.com/escapedcat/angular-phonecat-webpack-gulp). Very simple step by step example.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! Any chance you could extend your angular webpack example to show how you can load extra modules or controllers at runtime?

Comment: @Nikos No problem :) I might actually leave that out of the example, because I feel like people find it useful now mainly because of it's extreme barebones-ness. Maybe we can talk about that in an issue in the project. Could you make one, and we can chat there? 

For the record, it's a bit more complicated to lazy load things in runtime because of how the angular module system works. You'll have to combine lazy loading as per pete hunt's example + https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad

Comment: @JeffLing sure I've created a repo to hold this: https://github.com/QuantumInformation/angular-webpack-lazy-loading, although I won't use coffee for it)

Comment: I actually meant for us to create an issue, but I like the idea of making a new project that might contain a good example.

Comment: @Nikos That's not lazy-loading. [This](http://michalzalecki.com/lazy-load-angularjs-with-webpack/) is lazy-loading.

Answer (score -3):

Hi you should go with webpack as it supports multiple filetypes (css, js +++), and can separate code in multiple modules.