# AngularJS and Webpack Integration

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, lazy-loading, webpack

I am looking for some help with using [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/docs/) for a large AngularJS application. We are using folder structure based on feature (each feature/page has a module and they have controllers, directives). I have successfully configured webpack to get it working with Grunt, which produces one single bundle. I want to create chunks as its going to be a large app, we would like to load modules (page/feature) artifacts asynchronously.

I am going through some of the webpack example to use `'code splitting'` using `require([deps],fn )` syntax. However I couldn't get the chunks lazy-loaded. First of all, I don't know where exactly, I would need to import these chunks before AngularJS would route the user to next page. I am struggling to find a clear separation of responsibility.

Did someone point me to an example AngularJS application where webpack is used to load controllers/directives/filters asynchronously after each route?

Few of the links I am following: 
[Should I use Browserify or Webpack for lazy loading of dependancies in angular 1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605099/should-i-use-browserify-or-webpack-for-lazy-loading-of-dependancies-in-angular-1)
https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto#9-async-loading
http://dontkry.com/posts/code/single-page-modules-with-webpack.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sagar Ganatra wrote a helpful [blog post](http://www.sagarganatra.com/2014/08/lazy-loading-angularjs-components-using-providers.html) about code splitting.

Suprisingly code splitting isn't really supported by angular's module system. However, there is a way to achieve code splitting by saving a reference to angular's special providers during the config-phase.

> [...] when Angular initializes or bootstraps the application, functions - controller, service etc,. are available on the module instance. Here, we are lazy loading the components and the functions are not available at a later point; therefore we must use the various provider functions and register these components. The providers are available only in the config method and hence we will have to store a reference of these providers in the config function when the application is initialized.

```
window.app.config([
    '$routeProvider',
    '$controllerProvider',
    '$compileProvider',
    '$filterProvider',
    '$provide',
    function ($routeProvider, $controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide) {

        $routeProvider.when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'components/login/partials/login.html',
            resolve: {
                load: ['$q', '$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope) {

                    var deferred = $q.defer();

                    // lazy load controllers, etc.
                    require ([
                        'components/login/controllers/loginController',
                        'components/login/services/loginService'
                    ], function () {

                        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                            deferred.resolve();
                        });

                    });

                    return deferred.promise;
                }]
            }
        });


        //store a reference to various provider functions
        window.app.components = {
            controller: $controllerProvider.register,
            service: $provide.service
        };

    }
]);
```

Now inside your `loginController` for instance you write

```
app.components.controller('loginController');
```

to define your new controller lazily.

If you want to lazy-load your templates too I recommend to use the [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). There you can specify a `templateProvider` which is [basically a function to load templates async](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#templates)

Comment: thank you, i also find that calling $apply for many times is not correct.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply maybe once per each route should be ok, i guess.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. Basically you have to decide: Do I wait for every component to load before calling $apply or do I propagate the update as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quote from
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/150

webpack is a module bundler not a javascript loader. It package files from local disk and don't load files from the web (except its own chunks).

Use a javascript loader, i. e. script.js

```
var $script = require("scriptjs");
$script("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js", function() {
  // ...
});
```